# Job not running in Firebase job dispatcher when google play services version is incompatible

Tags: android, job-scheduling

I am using [Firebase Job Dispatcher](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-jobdispatcher-android) library for scheduling jobs in Android. Since I am having an explicit dependency on gcm, I am including the dependency as follows.

```
compile 'com.firebase:firebase-jobdispatcher-with-gcm-dep:0.5.0'.
compile "com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:8.4.0"
```

The documentation states that if the device is below Lollipop and Google Play services is not available on that device, then it will use AlarmManager instead.

> 2: Uses AlarmManager to support API levels <= 21 if Google Play
>   services is unavailable.

While testing I came across a device which had Android version 4.2.2 and Google Play services 7.5.62, but the job never runs on this device. Ideally, t should be invoked by AlarmManager according to the documentation.

Answer (score 0):

According to the documentation, it uses Google Play Services when Android Version is < 21

The line about AlarmManager, that you mentioned, is related to index 2 of the table presented [here](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-jobdispatcher-android) and it's talking about evernote/android-job library

Usually, if the device has Google Play Services, they are all in close to the latest version so it shouldn't be a problem.

did you try running:

```
adb shell dumpsys activity service GcmService
```

to see if the task is scheduled?

Comment: From the documentation, no one can make out that the line related to AlarmManager is related to evernote library. Even in the issues which I raised, they replied the same thing. But it is definitely not obvious.

Comment: Yes, I wrote the above command, and I am not able to see the job record. Thanks.

Comment: it would be better to find out why this device doesn't have the latest google play services, or at least find out if you update it, will the issue still continue?